# Fill missing values in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, data-scrubbing

I have the following problem: I have a dataframe with several columns. (See below) I am trying to fill in missing values. Concretely, I only want to fill in values when I have a datapoint *before* and one *after* the missing value *and* when they are equal. Note, I also have different IDs, so I want to do this for each ID. In the example below for example I would like to fill in a 1 for row 2 in year 2017 and in the penultimate row for ID 2 I would like to fill in a 2 (in both cases I have the same value "surrounding" the missing value). I do not want to fill in the last rows' value.

| ID | Year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016 | 1 |
| 1 | 2017 | -8 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 |
| 2 | 2016 | -8 |
| 2 | 2017 | 2 |
| 2 | 2018 | 2 |
| 2 | 2019 | - 8 |
| 2 | 2020 | 2 |
| 3 | 2017 | 4 |
| 3 | 2018 | 4 |
| 3 | 2019 | -9 |

I am somewhat clueless as to how to approach this problem. I have tried using group_by but I don't see a clear way to do it.

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `if_else` and `lead` and `lag` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, w = FALSE)

dat |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(value = if_else(value < 0 &
    (lag(value, default = "-99") == lead(value, default = "-999")),
  lag(value), value
  )) |>
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>       ID  Year value
#>    <int> <int> <chr>
#>  1     1  2016 1    
#>  2     1  2017 1    
#>  3     1  2018 1    
#>  4     2  2016 -8   
#>  5     2  2017 2    
#>  6     2  2018 2    
#>  7     2  2019 2    
#>  8     2  2020 2    
#>  9     3  2017 4    
#> 10     3  2018 4    
#> 11     3  2019 -9
```

**Note 1:** Instead of the default `NA` I used a `-99` and a `-999` as the `default` for `lag` and `lead`. Otherwise the `if_else` would replace some values with an `NA`.

**Note 2:**: In row 7 of your example data the missing value was a `- 8`. I assumed that this was a typo and replaced it by a `-8`.

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
  Year = c(
    2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L,
    2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L
  ),
  value = c(
    "1", "-8", "1", "-8", "2", "2",
    "-8", "2", "4", "4", "-9"
  )
)
```

Comment: Great thank you so much! I am wondering why the default ```-99``` or ```-999``` makes a difference here. Do you know?

Comment: Yeah. When using the default `NA` in any row where `lead` or `lag` will return an NA the value would be replaced by NA. That's why I switched to -99 and -999.